# Try-Catch tasks in GruntJS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is there a way to catch when a GruntJS task fails and act upon it?

The `--force` flag doesn't help, because I need to know if something broke along the way, and do something about it.

I tried some arrangement similar to a try-catch, however it doesn't work. That is because `grunt.registerTask` pushes tasks into a queue - the execution is not synchronous.

```
  grunt.registerTask('foo', "My foo task.", function() {
    try {
      grunt.task.run('bar');
    } catch (ex) {
      // Handle the failure without breaking the task queue
    }
  });
```

Creative javascript ideas are welcome as well as GruntJS know-how.

Comment: It looks like the [event API](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.event) is what will eventually allow you to do this, but that isn't slated to be finished until v0.5 [according to the issue backlog](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1167).

Comment: @jakerella Quite unfortunately, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This ugly beast should work for you:

```
  grunt.registerMultiTask('foo-task', 'my foo task', function() {
    try {
      console.log(this.data);
      throw new Error('something bad happened!');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Ooops:', e);
    }

    return true;
  });

  grunt.registerTask('foo', 'Runs foo.', function() {
    grunt.config('foo-task', {
      hello: 'world'
    });
    grunt.task.run('foo-task');
  });
```

Run it via: `grunt foo`

Output:

```
Running "foo" task

Running "foo-task:hello" (foo-task) task
world
Ooops: Error: something bad happened!
    at Object.<anonymous> 

    <stacktrace here>    

Done, without errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but like in any Javascript code you could **add an Event Listener** to grunt object and **fire event from tasks** when you need it...

Don't know if this could exactly fit your question but i would give it a try.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So... where exactly do I do that? Grunt's code's not mine

Comment: Just try something like use `require("events");`

and then write some code like this

`grunt.on("taskFailed", function(message){
     console.error("Error found "+message)
});`

and in any task use `grunt.emit("taskFailed", message);`

It's just an idea so if you get any result comment! haha